# Why <div class="clear"></div> used?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, clearfix

I'll adapt my self to what [52framework.com](http://www.52framework.com) offers. (HTML5, CSS3, JS framework)
Despite watching grid tutorial video and inspecting other [demo](http://demo.52framework.com/) source codes, I couldn't understand why framework used `<div class="clear"></div><!-- clear -->` code at 12th line.

Code below's address is: http://demo.52framework.com/demos/framework/grid.html

```
<body>
<div class="row">
<header>        
        <div class="logo col_7 col">52framework</div><!-- logo col_7 -->        
            <nav class="col_9 col">
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#navigation">navigation 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#navigation">navigation 2</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="http://www.enavu.com">enavu network</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav><!-- nav col_9 -->
        <div class="clear"></div><!-- clear -->
    </header>
</div><!-- row -->
...
```

This code below is also from same source but as you see `<div class="clear"></div><!-- clear -->` piece of code isn't used here even though more partition has been done here.

```
<!-- this section shows off the grid and how it can be used -->
<section class="row" id="grid">
    <h2>Grid Framework</h2>
    <div class="col col_8">
        col_8
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col_1">col_1</div>
            <div class="col col_7">col_7
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col_3">col_3</div>
                    <div class="col col_4">col_4</div>
                </div><!-- row -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- col_8 -->
  <div class="col col_8">
        col_8
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col_4">4</div>
            <div class="col col_4">4</div>
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- col_8 -->
  <div class="col_16 col" style="margin-top:15px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col_9">col_9</div>
            <div class="col col_7">col_7</div>
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- col_16 -->
  <div class="col_16 col">
        <a href="http://www.52framework.com/documentation/" class="documentation">Grid Framework Documentation</a>
    </div><!-- col_16 -->
</section><!-- row -->
```

### Related CSS codes:

```
.clear { clear:both; display:block; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden; height:0px;}

.col {
    margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.row{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row .row {
    margin: 0 -10px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Column widths, and element width based on grid */

.col_1, .width_1     {  width:40px;  }
.col_2, .width_2     {  width:100px; }
.col_3, .width_3     {  width:160px; }
.col_4, .width_4     {  width:220px; }
.col_5, .width_5     {  width:280px; }
.col_6, .width_6     {  width:340px; }
.col_7, .width_7     {  width:400px; }
.col_8, .width_8     {  width:460px; }
.col_9, .width_9     {  width:520px; }
.col_10, .width_10   {  width:580px; }
.col_11, .width_11   {  width:640px; }
.col_12, .width_12   {  width:700px; }
.col_13, .width_13   {  width:760px; }
.col_14, .width_14   {  width:820px; }
.col_15, .width_15   {  width:880px; }
.col_16, .width_16   {  width:940px; }
```

Comment: It is required to fix two-column problem (using float-prop) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best/1633170#1633170 You can delete clearer, and see for yourself

Comment: It is there to clear all the previous float alignments like float left or right & etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a method used to [clear the `float` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/1317805) your `nav` has obtained through its `.col` class. Without this the content following your `nav` element may appear alongside your `nav` element rather than below it.

For further reading, see Chris Coyier's [The How and Why of Clearing Floats](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/).

Comment: @Andre It's also worth mentioning that most developers now avoid the need for an extra element just to clear the floats by using the "after" psuedo element on the containing to clear the floats on content child elements. The "row" class will effectively clear the float of any child elements in your second example due to the overflow value, but I'd have to say this isn't considered best practice any more and you may want to look at another CSS framework.