# Why <div class="clear"></div> didn't used?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, clearfix

*Hi, sometimes learning something makes you more confused, I am in that position right now, thanks in advance.*

I asked a question in this address: [Why <div class="clear"></div> used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234175/why-div-class-clear-div-used)

After getting the answer and accepting (I also read the links given in comments section), now I've 2nd and 3rd questions.

According to the input codes given in related question,

1. Why [grid demo code](http://demo.52framework.com/demos/framework/grid.html) below didn't use `<div class="clear"></div>`? Again there exist 2 sets of two *floating div elements* so isn't it suitable to use `<div class="clear"></div>` just after the *last floating div elements*?

I explicitly mention that I would expect `<div class="clear"></div>` code in 2 places: Just after `<div class="col col_7">` and just after `<div class="col col_4">`

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col_1">col_1</div>
        <div class="col col_7">col_7
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col_3">col_3</div>
                <div class="col col_4">col_4</div>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- col_8 -->
```

2. The owner of accepted answer wrote that: "Without this the content following your nav element **may** appear alongside your nav element rather than below it." Since he used MAY grammar & I deleted `<div class="clear"></div>` and saw that nothing has changed in output for IE9 and Chrome 25.0.1364.172; what maked him to write MAY? Old browsers (especially old IE versions)?

Comment: Old IE versions, especially  IE6 and IE7 tend to misbehave when it comes to `float`.

Comment: there is overflow: hidden on a .row class, this is why we don't need element that clears floats

Comment: There are many ways of clearing floats: see this http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101 for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your **CSS** that is associated with the different *classes/ids/elements* in your **HTML**.

`<div class="clear"></div>` **ALWAYS** has some css associated with it, that is:

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

The above **CSS** is what makes it prevent that floating issue.  That said...  Using a "clear div" as you have shown above is one of many ways to do this.

In your particular case, given this HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col col_1">col_1</div>
        <div class="col col_7">col_7
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col_3">col_3</div>
                <div class="col col_4">col_4</div>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- col_8 -->
```

It is **very likely** that the class of "row" has the `clear: both;` property in CSS.  That would explain why when you remove the clear div, it stayed the same.  Essentially you didn't need the clear div, because the row class already has the **CSS** attached to it to prevent that issue from happening.

The selector probably looks like this:  `.row { clear: both; }` The `.row` class probably has other CSS associated with it as well, another very likely property is `overflow: hidden;`  That property can also effect how your divs and surrounding divs interact/behave next to each other.

**To summarize:**  It is `NOT` the *HTML* `<div class="clear"></div>` that prevents this floating issue from happening.  It **IS** the *CSS* property and value `clear: both;` which can be applied to any HTML element that prevents the issue from occurring.

Some resources:
[CSS Wiki on Overflow property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/overflow)
[CSS Wiki on Clear property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear)

Hopefully this clears that up for you?  (pardon the pun haha)